# Virtualhost problems. Have two vhost files but results are unexpected 2nd site does not load properly

Tags: wordpress, apache, apache2, virtualhost, vhosts

I have 1 ubuntu 14.04 server from DO and two independant WordPress installations I'm trying to run off the same server

Have two apache vhost config files:
`000-default.conf and 001-default.conf`

Now when navigating to `domain1.com` everything works flawlessly. The entire website is working as expected. But there is a problem with going to `domain2.com` it will automatically redirect to `domain1.com`. Basically the problem is I can't get to the WordPress installation screen on `domain2.com`

Here is the conf file under sites available for domain1.com (000-default.conf):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin email@gmail.com
    ServerName domain1.com
    ServerAlias www.domain1.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        <Directory /var/www/html/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

config file for domain2.com (001-default.conf):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin email@gmail.com
    ServerName domain2.com
    ServerAlias www.domain2.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/htmlposts
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/htmlposts>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>    
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Additional information:
In /var/www/html I have the WordPress files for domain1.com and everything works.

In /var/www/htmlposts/ I have extracted the WordPress files for domain2.com
it looks like this: http://prntscr.com/d4h9gu

I have created an index.html file in `/var/ww/htmlposts` which is the directory for `domain2.com` and when I navigate to `domain2.com/index.html` the file [displays as expected](http://prntscr.com/d4hhqh) but when I navigate to `domain2.com/wp-admin/install.php` which should start the wp installation process for instance #2 "domain2.com" it shows an already installed error which looks like this: http://prntscr.com/d4hhav

There are two databases on the server. One is for domain1.com and the other database is an empty one that I created for domain2.com. Both are correctly pointed in their respective wp-config.php files.

Comment: Are you trying to setup this on multi-site wordpress or are these domains on different installs of wordpress?

Comment: They are totally different installs of WordPress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you compare the config.php of the 2 sites. Make sure that the database names in both the config.php files are different.

Comment: Both of the wp-config.php files are pointing to different databases which are both present on the server. I'll update the question to clarify that part. The wp-config for domain1.com is a complete database which was imported from a migrated site. This one is working. The domain2.com database was created but is currently empty. The domain2.com wp-config.php file is pointing to the newly created but empty database. I think the wordpress installation (if i can get to that screen) will create the tables etc needed in the database. Thanks for your reply. Any other possibilities?

Comment: Can you try changing the table prefix in wp-config.php of the second domain to something different than the first domain.

Comment: Thank you for informing me about the prefix. I went into the mysql database and seen that I had imported domain1.com database into the domain2.com database and the site url from said database was redirecting to domain1.com. You did solve my question. Cheers zapping!